# dismissible option not working at materialize css

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I want to close the modal when the user click outside it, however, my code is not working. This is my first project with `Materialize`, so I dont have any idea why it isnt working. Here is a simple code of what I did:

> Inside head tag:

```
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

> Inside body tag:

```
      <!-- Modal Trigger -->
      <button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal1 modal-trigger">Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal Structure -->
      <div id="modal1" class="modal">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Modal Header</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat ">Disagree</a>
            <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
         </div>
      </div>
```

> Inside scripts tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
                  dismissible: true
              });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $(document).click(). Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $("#modal1").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: when i click the button to open it, it doesnt work using this

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
if($("#modal1").is(":visible"))
        $("#modal1").hide();
    });
});
```